# Make Eclipse forget “remember my decision” for Terminate/relaunch application

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, ide

While debugging java application in eclipse, the dialog for opting Relaunch/terminate appeared. I have selected the option to terminate the application, but now unable to change this option.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse settings, section `Java` > `Debug`, try checking the box 'Show error when hot code replace fails'.